# Make APScheduler run in background in web app

Tags: python, scheduling, flask, job-scheduling

I have a Flask web app, that shows information from a rss feed. I want to process the rss feed regularly, e.g every 30 minutes. Extract some of the information and store it in a sqlite db.

But I can't figure out how to schedule a function to certain intervals.

I have used the APScheduler, and my code is the following:

```
def main():
    # Start the scheduler
    filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'tmp')) + '\\' + 'spider.log'
    logging.basicConfig(filename=filename, level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(levelname)s[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s')
    sched = Scheduler()
    sched.start()
    sched.add_interval_job(run_job, minutes=30)
    time.sleep(9999)
```

I have a **run.py** function

```
from app import app, spider

spider.main()
app.run(debug=True)
```

The `app.run(debug=True)` starts the Flask web app. The problem is that the code never reaches `app.run`.

So is it possible to spawn another process to handle the `spider.main()` call, and run the process in the background? Or should I use another approach?

**NB:** I know I could use Flask-Celery, but for this small app, that seems too heavyweight...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `time.sleep` - when you run `spider.main` it starts your scheduler and then puts the process to sleep for 9999 seconds - after which it will run the next line.  So `app.run` will start ~2.78 hours after `spider.main` started.

So `spider` should look like this:

```
def main():
    # Start the scheduler
    filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'tmp')) + '\\' + 'spider.log'
    logging.basicConfig(filename=filename, level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(levelname)s[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s')
    sched = Scheduler()
    sched.start()
    sched.add_interval_job(run_job, minutes=30)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!

I had based my code on this answer APScheduler not starting, and could not make it work without the sleep, but re-arranging the code makes it work without the sleep.